# PDO login.php needs help finishing

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I'm new with PDO, I need help finishing the rest of this block of code for my login.php, can someone please help me out here?

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><br />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
    <input type="submit">
</form>


<?php
    if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
  try{
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lr;", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
    $result->execute($query);

  }  catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'ERROR', $e->getMessage();
  }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? What are you struggling with?

Comment: It appears that you're looking at what to do with that `:username` and `:password`, then figuring out how to successfully run a query using PDO. Is that correct?

Comment: I need help finishing my login.php, I don't know the next step.

Comment: Just so you know, questions of the kind "will you write/finish this for me" are generally discouraged here. This is because it's harder to learn if someone does it for you, and in any case it creates quite localised content that will probably be put on hold. It's better to find _what_ you are stuck on, and then ask about that if the manual doesn't give the answer. I should think the manual would have a complete example of this, either in the main body, or in the comments.

Comment: *"I need help finishing my login.php, I don't know the next step."* - **A:** The manual and Google. Oh lookah dat... they rhyme.

Comment: A login system will need to use sessions as well, so that's worth looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prepare statement returns an object, you can execute that object. Thus $query->execute() - the first parameter of execute can be an array. Alternatively, you can use the bindParam function first on that same $query object instead of passing an array though.

Anyways, here you are:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
  try{
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lr;", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
    $result = $query->execute(array(':username' => $_POST['username'], ':password' => $_POST['password']));

  }  catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'ERROR', $e->getMessage();
  }
} 
?>
```

Edit: also it's really bad practice to let applications use your root database user. You should get in the habit of giving users specific database permissions in the long run. Say a user that only has full permissions to one database.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that passwords should not be stored in plain text, and that PHP now offers hashing routines for this purpose.